# How to execute a Bash command using an Electron platform in Cordova

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, dom, electron

I'm trying to use [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) that now includes [Electron](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/guide/platforms/electron/index.html) to create a Desktop App for Linux.

I want a button that fires a shell command:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec

document.querySelector('button').onclick = () =>
  exec('ls -la', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout)
  })
```

Electron integrates Chromium with Node.js but deactivated by default in Cordova. [After activating it](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/guide/platforms/electron/index.html#how-to-support-nodejs-and-electron-apis), I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Note: this simple button click example is working fine with [Electron Quick Example](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) but when I try to do the same using Cordova + Electron `require is not defined`

Do I need to configure extra parameters and/or execute my `index.js` in a different scope?

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method. It is only possible by using Electron without Cordova. You need to require the "child_process" in your Electron's main.js. Cordova produces this file automatically and may update it if you update the version. You can add the above codes manually to the `"www\cdv-electron-main.js"` and `"platform_www\cdv-electron-main.js"` or you can set a Cordova hook. for example, a before_run hook:

```
<platform name="electron">
    <hook type="before_run" src="hooks/beforeRun.js" />
</platform>
```

in your beforeRun.js file add this codes:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function(ctx) {
    // Make sure electron platform is part of build
    if (!ctx.opts.platforms.includes('electron')) return;

    const platformRoot = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/electron');
    
    const main1 = path.join(platformRoot, 'www/cdv-electron-main.js');
    const main2 = path.join(platformRoot, 'platform_www/cdv-electron-main.js');

    const extra = "const electron = require('child_process');" +
          "document.querySelector('button').onclick = () =>\n" +
               "  exec('ls -la', (err, stdout, stderr) => {\n" +
                                   "    console.log(stdout)\n" +
                                                         "  })";

    fs.appendFile(main1, extra, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!');
    });
    fs.appendFile(main2, extra, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!');
    });
};
```

this will add your const and on click function to the Electron's main JS files. You may need to clear before every run as the hook **will add the above code to the end of the files multiple times**. You can set a checker value to prevent this if you need it.